# I get MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype when sending MPI_Type_vector

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I have a 3d array (like a cube) and I want to send  its surfaces as 2d array. I defined three datatype for xy, yz and xz planes and send them. But I keep getting the following error:

```
[Munny:8034] *** An error occurred in MPI_Send
[Munny:8034] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[Munny:8034] *** MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype
[Munny:8034] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 8034 on
node Munny exiting without calling "finalize". This may
have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpiexec (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Munny:08033] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[Munny:08033] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

This is the simplified version of my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int prev = 0;
    int curr = 1;
    global_err = 10E4;
    N = atof(argv[1]);
    s = cbrt(world_size); // world_size is always cube
    cube_edge_size = (N + 1 / s) + 2; // +2 is for ghost points
    double**** arr = new double***[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        arr[i] = new double**[cube_edge_size];
        for (int j = 0; j < cube_edge_size; ++j){
            arr[i][j] = new double*[cube_edge_size];
            for (int k = 0; k < cube_edge_size; ++k)
                arr[i][j][k] = new double[cube_edge_size];
        }
    }

    MPI_Datatype MPI_xy_plane;
    MPI_Datatype MPI_yz_plane;
    MPI_Datatype MPI_xz_plane;


    MPI_Type_vector(cube_edge_size, cube_edge_size,cube_edge_size*cube_edge_size, MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_xz_plane) ;
    //other definitions ...
    MPI_Request req[12];
    MPI_Status stats[12];

    while (global_err > 10E-4) {
        double local_err = 0;
        prev = 1 - prev;
        curr = 1 - prev;
        // send values to other processors - non blocking
        if(world_rank % s != 0){
            // not on the left surface of the cube
            MPI_Isend(&arr[curr][0][1][0], 1, MPI_xz_plane, world_rank - 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[2]);
        }
       //... other sends


        // get values from other processors - blocking
        if(world_rank % s != s-1){
            // not on the right surface of the cube
            MPI_Irecv(&arr[prev][0][0][0], 1, MPI_xz_plane, world_rank + 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[8]);
        }
       // ... other receives

        MPI_Waitall(12,req,stats);

        for (int i = 1; i < cube_edge_size-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; i < cube_edge_size-1; i++) {
                for (int k = 1; i < cube_edge_size-1; i++) {
                    // calculate new values
                    arr[curr][i][j][k] = arr[prev][i][j][k] + k * 0.2;//do some  other calculation
                    // calculate error
                    local_err += abs(arr[curr][i][j][k] - arr[prev][i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }

        MPI_Allreduce(&local_err, &global_err, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Since `arr` is 4d I am not sure if this is true. I need to store current and previous values. I tried the same code by changing `arr` to 3d but I got the same error message.

Comment: you need to `MPI_Type_commit()` your datatype before using it in communications.

Comment: thank you! I missed that one

Comment: I am not familiar with `MPI_Type_vector` but I don't think it will work with dynamically-allocated multi-dimensional array. Note that for efficiency/performance reasons, multi-dimensional arrays are usually stored in memory as a 1-D array (and, `MPI_Type_vector` assumes that). Simply create a 1-D array of size `2 * cube_edge_size * cube_edge_size * cube_edge_size`.

Comment: Right, jagged arrays should be avoided when MPI is involved. Since this is C++, Boost multidimensional arrays could be a better fit here.

Comment: My code wasn't working until I saw your comment about dynamically allocated arrays. Thank you so much @DanielLangr!